# Has anyone seen a programming language that handles threads like this?

Tags: multithreading, posix

Most of the multithreaded work I have done has been in C/C++, Python, or Delphi (Object Pascal).  All on Windows.  I'll use Delphi for my discussion here.  Delphi has a nice class called TThread which abstracts the thread creation process.  The class provides an Execute method which is the created thread's thread function.  You override that method and typically create a loop within it that exits when the thread is terminated.  You do the thread's work inside the loop.

One of the recurring tasks that crops up is keeping track (carefully) of which code gets executed in the thread's context and which code gets executed by external threads in an external context, with synchronization objects guarding data shared by the threads.  All basic thread programming stuff.  One of the recurring annoyances is creating functions to allow external threads to submit or retrieve data, and moving data from public thread-safe memory objects to those private to the thread and back the other way.

I was wondering if anyone has ever seen a programming language that makes this simpler?  Here's what I would love as a programming thread idiom.  Let's take a Delphi TThread sub-class created for this discussion.  Suppose I could mark class methods with one of three keywords like Private, PublicExecuteInAnyContext, or PublicExecuteInPrivateContext.  Here's how they would work.

Private: Private methods would only execute in the thread's context.  The compiler would automatically add code that would raise an exception if a code path led to that method being executed in a context outside of the host thread.  (E.g. - "Error, attempt to execute method private to thread $AEB from thread $EE0").

PublicExecuteInAnyContext: methods marked as such could be called by the thread that owns the method and any external thread.  Any data objects referenced in these methods would automatically be guarded with synchronization objects, with the option to override the default choice and supply your own.  (Mutex or semaphore instead of Critical Section, etc.)

PublicExecuteInPrivateContext: Methods marked with this keyword would execute in the thread's context, but are callable by any thread.  This option would allow for two strategies for dealing with calls to such methods by external threads:

1) Mode 1 - Block calling thread: the calling thread would block until the method returned.  In other words the compiler would automatically write code to make the calling thread would block.  Any parameters passed by the calling thread would be copied into variables private to the host thread.  The method would not execute until the host thread received control.  When the host thread exited the method the calling thread would be released and would have any results returned by the method copied into it's own private variable space.

2) Mode 2 - Do not block the calling thread: this would allow for the additional argument of a callback function.  Any parameters passed to the method by an external thread would be copied into the thread's private variable space.  The compiler would again hold the execution of the method until the host thread received control, but would let the calling thread continue without blocking.  When the host thread completed execution of the method, if a callback function was specified, it would call that function ** but in the context of the original thread that called the method, not in the host thread context **.

A language that would provide this kind of automatic thread handling would, at least to me, be a lot more fun to do multithreading with then the way I have to do it now.  Has anybody seen a programming language, or a module/hack for one of the mainstream languages, that provides this kind of multi-threading model?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it matches your description exactly, but [Erlang](http://erlang.org/) provides one of the easiest concurrency models I've seen. It uses a share-nothing approach, which may or may not sound appealing to you, but I found it really interesting. It's also really easy to create distributed systems with it, if you ever have the need. Check out ["Getting Started with Erlang"](http://erlang.org/download/getting_started-5.4.pdf), it's a great tutorial that covers almost all parts of the language.

Comment: Yes, read the docs.  Play with Erlang.  It's designed around creating easy-to-use, lightweight, processes with a small memory footprint.  
http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to mention. LabVIEW really makes starting with multi threading a breeze. I just found some article on the Internet which actually explains this in a better way:

> If you have programmed in a
>   traditional, textual language before,
>   the data-flow paradigm of Labview can
>   be somewhat hard to embrace. The
>   data-flow paradigm stipulates that it
>   does not matter where on the 2D
>   surface of the block diagram a
>   particular component is placed in
>   relation to other components, but what
>   other components it is wired to. A
>   particular component-node does not
>   execute until all its inputs are
>   available; it executes, however, as
>   soon as all its inputs are available,
>   regardless of what else might be
>   executing at the same time, that is -
>   in parallel with potentially many
>   other things.
>
> You need extensive experience with
>   multi-threading programming in a
>   traditional language, however, to
>   truly appreciate how easy it is to
>   achieve multi-threading with LabVIEW
>   and how naturally the parallelism
>   arises - whether intentionally, or
>   not. While LabVIEW does not magically
>   dissolve all the challenges related to
>   parallel processing, it certainly
>   makes it considerably simpler to get
>   started with it. In fact, in contrast
>   with the traditionally sequential
>   textual programming languages, its is
>   the sequential execution that comes at
>   a price in LabVIEW - parallelism is
>   almost free.

Taken from http://saberrobotics.org/?id=34